# Different start status for some ticket types

Tags: jira

I'm setting up an advanced workflow in Jira and I have some ticket types that I'd like to automatically be transitioned to a specific status upon creation.

Normally our tickets start in the backlog, and then go through some status to get to "Ready for Development" and then some picks that ticket and transitions it to "In Development".

What I would like is for some ticket types to automatically get to "Ready for Development" or "In Development" when they are created.

This would be relevant for tickets representing a backport of a feature or bug fix to a previous version, or an issue ticket for another blocked ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the current workflow to another and in the new one to change the "Create Issue" transition to point to the "Ready for Development" step. Then in the workflow scheme assign the new workflow to the issue type representing this different kind of ticket. The drawback here is that you'll have to support two workflows instead of one, but I can't think of better solution.

Comment: Right. Didn't think of that.

But yeah, bummer to have to support two workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get more complex and use the Script Runner add-on and automatic transitions as noted at http://blogs.onresolve.com/2011/04/auto-transitions-in-jira-workflows/

Comment: That actually looks pretty cool. Would love to have access to that; unfortunately we're running OnDemand, and Script Runner isn't available there :(